# Regex Negation : Matching patterns other than specific strings

Tags: regex, sed, regex-negation

I am using a Voice-to-Text application which gives transcription files as output.. The transcribed text contains a few tags like `(s)` (for sentence beginning)..`(/s)`( for sentence end ).. `(VOCAL_NOISE)`(for un-recognized words).. but the text also contains unwanted tags like `(VOCAL_N)` , `(VOCAL_NOISED)` , `(VOCAL_SOUND)`, `(UNKNOWN)`.. i am using SED to process the text.. but cannot write an appropriate regex to replace all other tags except `(s)`, `(/s)` and `(VOCAL_NOISE)`, with the tag `~NS`.. would appreciate if someone could help me with it..

Example text:

```
(s) Hi Stacey , this is Stanley (/s) (s) I would (VOCAL_N) appreciate if you could call (UNKNOWN) and let him know I want an appointment (VOCAL_NOISE) with him (/s)
```

Output should be:

```
(s) Hi Stacey , this is Stanley (/s) (s) I would ~NS appreciate if you could call ~NS and let him know I want an appointment (VOCAL_NOISE) with him (/s)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should take care of it:

```
sed 's|([^)]*)|\n&\n|g;s@\n\((/\?s)\|(VOCAL_NOISE)\)\n@\1@g;s|\n\(([^)]*)\)\n|~NS|g' inputfile
```

Explanation:

- `s|([^)]*)|\n&\n|g` - divide the line by putting every parenthesized string between two newlines
- `s@\n\((/\?s)\|(VOCAL_NOISE)\)\n@\1@g` - remove the newlines around "(s)", "(/s)" and 
  "(VOCAL_NOISE)" (keepers)
- `s|\n\(([^)]*)\)\n|~NS|g` - replace anything else between newlines that is within parentheses with "~NS"

This works since newlines are guaranteed not to appear within a newly read line of text.

**Edit:** Shortened the command by using alternation `\(foo\|bar\)`

Previous version:

```
    sed 's|([^)]*)|\n&\n|g;s|\n\((/\?s)\)\n|\1|g; s|\n\((VOCAL_NOISE)\)\n|\1|g;s|\n\(([^)]*)\)\n|~NS|g' inputfile
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a dirty trick that is far from being optimal but it should work for you:

```
sed ' 
    s|(\(/\?\)s)|[\1AAA]|g; 
    s|(VOCAL_NOISE)|[BBB]|g; 

    s/([^)]*)/~NS/g; 

    s|\[\(/\?\)AAA\]|(\1s)|g; 
    s|\[BBB\]|(VOCAL_NOISE)|g'
```

The trick is to replace (s), (/s) and (VOCAL_NOISE) with patterns which are not present in the input text (in this case [AAA], [/AAA] and [BBB]); then we replace every instance of (.*) with ~NS; in the end we get back the fake patterns to their original value.

Answer (score 0):

I could suggest this using vim:

```
:%s/\((\w\+)\)\&\(\((s)\|(VOCAL_NOISE)\)\@!\)/\~NS/g
```

Using a shell (bash) you can do the following:

```
vim file -c '%s/\((\w\+)\)\&\(\((s)\|(VOCAL_NOISE)\)\@!\)/\~NS/g' -c "wq"
```

Make a backup first, I am not responsible for any damage if this is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Simply this ?

```
sed -E 's/\((VOCAL_N|UNKNOWN)\)/~NS/'
```

In this case, you'd have a blacklist (you know what to filter out). Or do you absolutely need a whitelist (you know what to NOT filter out) ?

Comment: @ DarkDust: thing is.. I cannot predict what unwanted Tags will occur.. i am only certain of the wanted Tags viz (s), (/s) and (VOCAL_NOISE).. the so called whitelist.. so, i need to keep the wanted Tags, while replacing the unwanted Tags with ~NS..

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -vRS=")" -vFS="(" '$2!~/s|\\s|VOCAL_NOISE/{$2="~NS"}RT' ORS=")"  file |sed 's/~NS)/~NS/g'
```